# Looping and Adding All Feature Classes From File Geodatabase Feature Dataset into Current Map

Tags: arcpy, layers, iteration

I need to add all features within a dataset called `MainSt` in a file geodatabase which is stored at following directory

> C:/Temp/Roads.gdb

to current map. using following code I am able to add them one by one but can you please let me know how I can loop and add them dynamically

```
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
    targetGroupLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Main Streets", df)[0]
    addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"C:\Temp\Roads.gdb\MainSt\trace_Fittings")
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayerToGroup(df, targetGroupLayer, addLayer, "BOTTOM")
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [`arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/listfeatureclasses.htm) and how that works in a `for loop.  See the Code Sample at the bottom of that page.

Then as you loop through the feature classes you just use your same code, with `addLayer` pointing at each feature class in the loop.

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Temp\Roads.gdb\MainSt"

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
targetGroupLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Main Streets", df)[0]

fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for fc in fcs:
    addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(fc)
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayerToGroup(df, targetGroupLayer, addLayer, "BOTTOM")
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

All I have changed in your code is to add the `arcpy.env.workspace`, `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()`, and the `for` loop, then re-point your feature class to the looped `fc`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your first step will be to determine how to create a [list of feature classes](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/listfeatureclasses.htm) in a particular feature dataset.

Once you have that you can use a `for` loop to iterate through it.